# Why are non-separated schemes schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In "the old days", e.g. in the famous texts by Grothendieck and Mumford, a scheme was defined as what we now call a *separated scheme*. (i.e. a scheme where the image of the morphism $\Delta:X \to X \times X$ is closed)

Nowadays, schemes are usually allowed to be separated. The question is then: *Do non-separated schemes naturally occur in nature?*

Comment: I assume that you know the usual examples, but would like to see non-separated schemes which really are of interest and which are studied by algebraic geometers? Would you also accept non-separated stacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moduli spaces and stacks tend to be non-separated. See for example [this poster](http://math.arizona.edu/~vpiercey/Hall.pdf) by David Rydh and Jack Hall. The example of the Picard scheme appears in [FGA explained](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FGA+explained), Ex. 9.4.14.

Comment: That link seems broken for me, it seems to have a couple extra characters at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the poster, a very good read. Also, I should definitely read some in "FGA explained".

Comment: The link to the poster is now dead, and it doesn't seem to be archived on the Wayback Machine. Could you briefly say what was on that poster?

Comment: Perhaps you can mail David Rydh. His address is on his website.

Answer (score 4):

Non-separated schemes also appear in GIT; i.e., when you want to define the quotient of a scheme by a group of automorphisms.